# reading an array in a function

Tags: arduino

I am trying using the arduino IDE to write a sketch. I have data in progmem and want to move the data with a function to a memory address allocated using malloc. My code is below:

```
const uint8_t Data_6 [256] PROGMEM = { 0x11, 0x39......};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  oddBallData (Data_6, 0x00, 256);
}
void main() {
} 
void oddBallData(const uint8_t *data, uint8_t mem, uint16_t bytes) {
  uint8_t *buff1 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(bytes));
  if (buff1 = 0) {
    Serial.println(F("FATAL ERROR - NO MEMORY"));
  }
  else {
    for (uint16_t x = 0; x < 6; x++ ) {
      buff1[x] = data[x];            //edited from data[0] to [x] made a mistake in post 
      Serial.println(buff1[x],HEX);
    }
  }
  buff1[0] = data[0];
  Serial.println(buff1[0],HEX); 
  free(buff1);
}
```

I have some data saved in progmem and want to write that data to a second device using i2c protocol. I have multiple constant arrays of data saved to my progmem, with different sizes. So I have used malloc to reserve some memory from the heap, inside of the function.

I have not been able to write the data from the progmem so I have stripped things back to so that I am just trying to point to the progmem data using malloc and then print it.

This is where I found a the problem. If I print a single array entry from the data constant. It prints the correct value. If I use a loop I get mixed results, the loop works as long as the condition check value is below 3 or sometimes below 6!!!...?
If above this value the entire print is just garbage. Can anyone explain what I am seeing?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was a working malloc on a microcontroller – you're not really running an OS that provides memory paging. Also, `sizeof(uint16_t bytes)` is always 2, so you could as well just have a two-element `uint8_t[]`

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Since when does `malloc` require paging? Tell that the early PCs, Macs, Ataris, Amigas etc! There are many MCUs which don't have a problem to support enough RAM (some even have enough built-in). It does not always require GiB to support dynamic memory allocation! Said that: Arduinoindeed is not among these platforms. Leat apart that `new` and `delete` would be the correct ways. Arduino is not C, but C++ based!

Comment: Marcus I'm sure malloc works on micro controllers, I have read a little and from what I gather malloc is definatly used. Thanks for pointing out about the (uint16 bytes). My logic was that I had to pass the data type along with the variable name.

Comment: @user1232141234213: This is not the place to discuss. There are platforms which are suitable for dynamic memory allocation using a heap-approach. Arduino is none of them! And for far by most bare-metal embedded systems it is a pretty bad idea anyway. **Even iff they have the hardware properties (primarily RAM) to resonably support it.** You might have read the wrong resources.

Comment: @Olaf: Ok, I never realised malloc could not be used with the Arduino, specifically the Atmega328p MCU. The only arguments I have seen for not using malloc is that it leaves holes in the heap, you have said this is not to be discussed here but if this relates to my question then surely it is?

Comment: `uint8_t *buff1 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(bytes));` --> `uint8_t *buff1 = malloc(sizeof *buff1 * 6);`  6 as `for()`  loop uses 6.

Comment: @Olaf sorry, you're right – malloc has nothing to do with paging; anyway, the point (and we agree on this) is that malloc makes no sense on an arduino

Comment: @MarcusMüller: As you can read I'm even with you that for most bare-metal applications where enough RAM is available (e.g. the STM32F4 family has more internal RAM than early PCs), it is nonsense at best, and often cause of failure in the longer term.

Comment: @user1232141234213: Sorry, this is not a duscussion forum. You might find a trail of bread-crumbs here and elsewhere by some research to get the picture. You definitively should get it if you learn how such algorithms typically work and think about the typical use-cases for embedded platforms. Also please understand you are not the first to ask this. At some point one gets tired of explaining things which canbe deduced with some effort. (As a bonus you will learn a lot more from own research than a specific explanation).

Comment: @Olaf please point out where this question has been asked before.

Comment: @Olaf having slept over this, I'm even pretty surprised there's a `malloc` symbol within the libc used at all – why? oh, why?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Doesn't this question answer it? :-{ ...

Comment: @Olaf I'd honestly would have expected things to be compiled with `gcc -nostdlib -nodefaultlib -lgcc -nostdinc`, and malloc to really not exist.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: This is Arduino, neither C nor (exactly) C++. Don't apply expectations for the standard libs to that platform

Comment: @Olaf note taken. Thanks! (I liked the first version of your comment better)

Comment: @MarcusMüller: (Me too, but I don't want another discussion if that is rude - against that poor Arduino platform, or ...;-) Self-censorship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again - AVR `PROGMEM` is not directly accessible from memory space, it needs different instruction than access into the `RAM`. If you are using it like this, you'll get `RAM` content on passed address, not the `FLASH` one. You have to use special functions for this. For example `memcpy_P(ram_buff,flash_ptr);` makes a copy from flash into the ram. Or you can read one byte by `pgm_read_byte(flash_ptr + offset)`

BTW: If you are using `Data_6[0]` and it's working, it's just because compiler sees it as a constant and constant can be replaced by its value compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is probably

```
uint8_t *buff1 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(bytes));
```

`sizeof(bytes)` returns the size of the variable (which is probably 2 bytes) so you are just allocating 2 bytes of memory. You should use the value directly, eg:

```
uint8_t* buff1 = malloc(bytes);
```

Mind that the cast **is not required in C** since a `void*` is convertible to any other pointer type directly.

Comment: Jack, thanks for the reply. I have tried your suggestion but the problem still remains.

Comment: Note that `oddBallData(const uint8_t *data, uint8_t mem, uint16_t bytes)` does not use `bytes` after `buff1 = malloc(...)`, but does iterate 6 times using `buff1[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you just forgot to `flush()`

try to do `Serial.flushI()` after `Serial.println(buff1[x],HEX);`

you can also check [flush documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Flush)